# Web API 2 versioning with Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Versioning

Tags: c#, asp.net, api-versioning, aspnet-api-versioning

I am using [ASP.NET Versioning Library](https://github.com/microsoft/aspnet-api-versioning), I have followed steps to add this library to a very basic ASP.NET Web API 2 project, Here are the contents of my files:
`Global.asax` file:

```
 public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start()
        {
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
            GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        }
    }
```

Web API Config:

```
  public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
            config.AddApiVersioning(c => c.AssumeDefaultVersionWhenUnspecified = true);   
        }
    }
```

First controller:

```
namespace WebApplication5.Controllers
{
    [ApiVersion("1.0")]
    [RoutePrefix("api1")]
    public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
        [Route("values")]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
        [Route("values/{id}")]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }
    }
}
```

Second controller:

```
namespace WebApplication5.Controllers
{
    [ApiVersion("2.0")]
    [RoutePrefix("api1")]
    [ControllerName("Values")]
    public class ValuesController2 : ApiController
    {
        [Route("values")]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }
        [Route("values/{id}")]

        // GET api/values/5
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the application and navigate to this url: `http://localhost:5428/api1/values?api-version=1.0` I get the desired results, But When I navigate to this url: `http://localhost:5428/api1/values?api-version=2.0` I encounter an error message stating that `No route providing a controller name with API version '2.0' was found to match request URI 'http://localhost:5428/api1/values'`, I was wondering what am I missing in this basic setup?

If I remove `[ControllerName]` attribute from `ValuesController2` nothing changes and the issue persists.

I tried to change the namespace of the second controller, But It didn't solve the problem either !

I am using version [3.0.1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Versioning) of this library.

Comment: Your question helped me understand how to implement versioning. I was searching for examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just realised what your issue is, the controller name should be `Values2Controller` not `ValuesController2`.

The controller is located using be convention on the name and it drops the Controller part but yours is Controller2 so I would guess it's not finding it as per the message you got back.

Comment: Wow ! It really worked, That was a very subtle point that I missed.

Comment: I don't want to take anything away from Andrew HB, but I did want to further elaborate why this happens. This is not due to API Versioning, but rather how ASP.NET Web API works. If you examine the [DefaultHttpControllerTypeResolver.IsControllerType](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Http/Dispatcher/DefaultHttpControllerTypeResolver.cs#L49) method, you'll see that a valid controller type **must** end with `Controller`, which your controller does not. As I recall, the history of that is to ignore non-abstract super types such as `XXXControllerBase`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on the validity of having the ApiVersion attribute on the controller, but on my implementation I have that attribute on my action e.g.

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class VersionDemoController
    {
        [ApiVersion("1.1")]
        [HttpGet("requestStuff")]
        public string RequestStuff()
        {
            return "Stuff using Version 1.1 API";
        }
    }
```

Update:
Just tried using the attribute on the controller and it seems to work fine, my namespaces are different with the action names the same.  I am using version 3.1.2 of the versioning package though.

Comment: I guess you are working with .net core version of this library! I am using the old .Net Web API 2